# Error using impshowpair function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging

When the use the following code

```
imshowpair(Image1, Image2,'montage');
```

The following error occurs

```
??? Undefined function or method 'imshowpair' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

I am using MATLAB version R2010a.

Give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imshowpair` was introduced in image processing toolbox for MATLAB 2012a. So you could upgrade your MATLAB.